# Python - Parse strings with variable repeating substring

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, substring

I am trying to do something which I thought would be simple (and probably is), however I am hitting a wall. I have a string that contains document numbers. In most cases the format is ***######-#-###*** however in some cases, where the single digit should be, there are multiple single digits separated by a comma (i.e. ***######-#,#,#-###***). The number of single digits separated by a comma is variable. Below is an example:

For the string below:

```
('030421-1,2-001 & 030421-1-002,030421-1,2,3-002, 030421-1-003')
```

I need to return:

```
['030421-1-001', '030421-2-001' '030421-1-002', '030421-1-002', '030421-2-002', '030421-3-002' '030421-1-003']
```

I have only gotten as far as returning the strings that match the ***######-#-###*** pattern:

```
import re
p = re.compile('\d{6}-\d{1}-\d{3}')
m = p.findall('030421-1,2-001 & 030421-1-002,030421-1,2,3-002, 030421-1-003')
print m
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Matt

Comment: i don't know how `findall` func would modify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '030421-1,2-001 & 030421-1-002,030421-1,2,3-002, 030421-1-003'
>>> it = re.finditer(r'(\b\d{6}-)(\d(?:,\d)*)(-\d{3})\b', s)
>>> for m in it:
    a, b, c = m.groups()
    for x in b.split(','):
        print a + x + c
...         
030421-1-001
030421-2-001
030421-1-002
030421-1-002
030421-2-002
030421-3-002
030421-1-003
```

Or using a list comprehension

```
>>> [a+x+c for a, b, c in (m.groups() for m in it) for x in b.split(',')]
['030421-1-001', '030421-2-001', '030421-1-002', '030421-1-002', '030421-2-002', '030421-3-002', '030421-1-003']
```

Comment: Awesome! That top example did the trick. I ran it on a test case of roughly 400 records and it did exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Impressive. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'\d{6}-\d(,\d)*-\d{3}'`.

`*` means "as many as you want (0 included)".
It is applied to the previous element, here `'(,\d)'`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I tried that but it did not return what I was expecting. It returned the following: [',2', '', ',3', '']

Comment: Yes, it returns the different matches, which are what is matched inside the different parenthesis. If you add parenthesis around the whole regexp: `('\d{6}-\d(,\d)*-\d{3}')`, [x[0] for x in m] will give you what you want.

Comment: thanks serialk, looks like we are getting closer, but still not quite there. adding the parentheses results in : [('030421-1,2-001', ',2'), ('030421-1-002', ''), ('030421-1,2,3-002', ',3'), ('030421-1-003', '')]

Comment: Have you tried [x[0] for x in m] ? This gets you the first element of every tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a single regular expression to try and parse this. Since it is essentially a list of strings, you might find it easier to replace the "&" with a comma globally in the string and then use split() to put the elements into a list.

Doing a loop of the list will allow you to write a single function to parse and fix the string and then you can push it onto a new list and the display your string.

```
replace(string, '&', ',')
initialList = string.split(',')
for item in initialList:
    newItem = myfunction(item)
    newList.append(newItem)

newstring = newlist(join(','))
```

Comment: Not really the question, and the format is really easy to match with a regexp. I didn't downvote because your proposal makes sense but I don't think it's the best advice to follow. OP didn't specify a format, so maybe the general case is more complicated than you think.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Serialk is correct, the general case can be way more complicated. The only given is that the string will contain substrings in the format of ######-#-### or ###-#(,# any number of times)-###. There may be all other types characters and text in the overall string (ex '0122.03, 0652.2 & 0652.5, ASSIGNMENT AND ASSUMPTION OF EASEMENT FOR POWER LINE PURPOSES, (EXPIRES WITH GROUND LEASE DATED  7/17/85 RECORDED AS INST NO. 167831 ON 7/30/85, SEE ALSO 030421-2-010) SEE 030421-2-020 & 030421-1-XXX'

Answer (score 0):

`(\d{6}-)((?:\d,?)+)(-\d{3})`

We take 3 capturing groups. We match the first part and last part the easy way. The center part is optionally repeated and optionally contains a ','. Regex will however only match the last one, so `?:` won't store it at all. What where left with is the following result:

```
>>> p = re.compile('(\d{6}-)((?:\d,?)+)(-\d{3})')
>>> m = p.findall('030421-1,2-001 & 030421-1-002,030421-1,2,3-002, 030421-1-003')
>>> m
[('030421-', '1,2', '-001'), ('030421-', '1', '-002'), ('030421-', '1,2,3', '-002'),  ('030421-', '1', '-003')]
```

You'll have to manually process the 2nd term to split them up and join them, but a list comprehension should be able to do that.